# Mongoose count items in sub document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have following schema:

```
{
    _id: 1,
    post: 'content',
    comments: [
        {
            id: 1,
            items: ['<other_doc_id',...] // assume 3 items
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            items: ['<other_doc_id',...] // assume 2 items
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to count number of items for all documents in a collection, like in above scenario it should return 5, and if we have another document with same comments then it should return 10.

**UPDATE**
This is my sample data

```
"comments": [
    {
        "id": {
            "$oid": "5a201f6d7295d76514a69a7c"
        },
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5a2e84cc9735111c147a359f"
        },
        "tags": [
            {
                "$oid": "5a251acb6eba8810f97e7abc"
            },
            {
                "$oid": "5a251ae66eba8810f97e7abd"
            }
        ],
        "items": [
            {
                "$oid": "5a201f767295d76514a69a7d"
            },
            {
                "$oid": "5a2512a1dc9a8c106c82226d"
            }
        ]
    }
],
```

**QUERY**

```
posts.aggregate([{
    "$project": {
        "count": {
            "$sum": {
                "$map": {
                    "input": "comments",
                    "as": "result",
                    "in": {
                        "$size": "$$result.items"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}]);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `$map` to count the `$size` of each items in comment array of documents followed by `$sum` to count all sizes.

```
db.collection_name.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "count": {
        "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$comments",
            "as": "result",
            "in": {
              "$size": "$$result.items"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Comment: Thanks, It makes sense, but it's giving me following error: `MongoError: input to $map must be an array not string`

Comment: This answer is useful for me, and doesn't cause any error.

Comment: @Veeram i am using same query as yours, i have updated my question with sample data that i have.

Comment: Works fine and outputs `{count:2}` for me with the data you have provided. Please add the query to the question. May be there is some typo.

Comment: @Veeram query added

Comment: You are missing $ in front of comments. Try `$comments`

Comment: Aaaah this is frustrating ... working now but its returning items count for each element, need to sum all the returning counts to show all items in all elements of all documents, understand what i am trying to achieve. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Np. `$project` stage will return count of items in a single document. Add `$group` after `$project` stage to return count across entire collection. Something like `{
    "$group": {
      "_id": null,
      "count": {
        "$sum": "$count"
      }
    }
  }`